# Is there a way to be notified when event listeners are added to a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a custom Vue component that does not render to HTML.

When the component is first mounted, I am able to loop through this.$listeners and optimize the underlying non-HTML event implementation accordingly (e.g. not to emit mousemove type events unless something is listening).

To complete this process I'd like to know when listeners are programatically added later through $on().

Is there any non-polling way to be notified of this? My current workaround is to listen for and emit *everything* but that is a poor solution.

---

Note that in some instances I want to be able to use the events in question, and others not.  For example:

```
<custom-component @eventThatWouldFireOften="doSomething" @anotherEvent="doMoreStuff"/>
```

and another usage might be simply.

```
<custom-component ref="custom"/>
...
mounted() {
 this.$refs.custom.$on('anotherEvent', ...)
}
```

So in the first case the result would be:

- `CustomComponent` tells the underlying API it wants to listen for `eventThatWouldFireOften` and `anotherEvent`
- `CustomComponent` receives `eventThatWouldFireOften` and `anotherEvent` events from the underlying API and re-emits them as Vue events that can be listened to using v-on or @ syntax.

..and the second case the result would be:

- `CustomComponent` tells underlying API it doesn't want to listen for anything just yet
- When the parent of `CustomComponent` is mounted it programatically listens for `anotherEvent`. That needs to be communicated down to the base API (what I'm trying to solve).

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me: if you don't want to emit a mousemove event because it's not being listened to, then you should stop that at the root level where the event is being captured, and stop it from being emitted to your custom component.

Comment: @Terry: Added a more detailed example that I hope illustrates why I can't just cease to listen for the event at the base API/root level.

Comment: There's a lot of logic to work out behind the rough spec you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll rework this into something more sensible when I get a chance.